# what is the definition of cardinal numbers, what is the necessary background I should have to understand cardinal number and ordinal numbers?

Tags: set-theory

I want to understand how cardinal numbers are considered a generalization of ordinal numbers, would you please recommend some good texts also.

Comment: This VSauce video is a pretty good start. https://youtu.be/SrU9YDoXE88

Comment: Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs. by Kenneth Kunen. Chapter 1, especially Sections 6,7,8,9,10.

Answer (score 3):

Cardinals are not a generalization of the ordinals.  Cardinals extend the notion of one, two, thee while ordinals extend the notion of first, second, third.  In the finite realm there is a natural bijection between these.  There are many countably infinite ordinals but only one countably infinite cardinal.  This is because adding one to an infinite cardinal does not increase it.  Basic set theory books will cover this.